# Run startActivityForResult from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-broadcast

Is it possible to `startActivityForResult` from something other than `activity`?

Eg: we have `broadcastReceiver` class which starts activity, those activity takes some action, `finishes` returning `result` which this `broadcastReceiver` class should interpret according to result itself(finish app or perform more sophisticated actions).

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver cannot handler `onActivityResult` callback.

A better idea would be to create a different `BroadcastReceiver` that handles the response of the activity started by first `Receiver`.

So you will have one `Receiver` that starts an activity on some action, the activity, in turn, sends a broadcast to other receiver which is supposed to perform further tasks